# How to change camera to current view on LAPTOP

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

How do I change camera to current view in **Mac Laptop?**
I am trying to do what "Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0" does on desktop version

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In user preferences, if you use "Emulate Numpad", it gives the regular 1-0 numbers the same functionality as the Numpad:

[image: Numpad]

Of course, if you don't want to go to the trouble of remapping your keys, you can always just select it manually from the view menu:

[image: View]

Comment: Thank you! :)..